# How can the parameters be unknown but the probability distribution be known?

Tags: econometrics, nonparametric

In an article (Nelson & Katzenstein, 2014) I came across the following sentence: ... “a fixed model of the economy with known parameters (or sometimes unknown parameters with known probability distributions).” (p. 380). I was wondering how the parameters can be unknown while the probability distributions are known. To my understanding, knowing a probability distribution entails knowing the parameters (the mean and variance). Can you help me reconcile this?

Comment: You are right, Taking it literally it is contradictory. But possibly when he says "known probability distributions" he may mean a known parametric family like the normal, gamma, and beta. In that case the parameters could be unknown. Maybe this can be reconciled by reading further in the text to get the context.

Comment: "...unknown parameters with known probability distributions" sounds like a way of saying that some numbers in an economic model might be considered as realizations of random variables with given distributions.  But without detailed knowledge of the context, one can only guess.

Comment: @Tea Theoretical considerations may give a model but not parameters. Moving outside the economic context, if one is sure that the conditions for a Poisson process are satisfied then the distribution of the number of events per fixed interval of time must be Poisson, even though we don't know the population parameter. Typically models (including Poisson process models) will really be approximations to truth -- though possibly widely accepted ones that might perform fairly well in general.

Answer (score 2):

When I took a mathematical statistics class, when talking about such as estimating the mean and variance of a normal distribution, the instructor always said we had a *family* of distributions. Every distribution in the family is normal, but with a different mean and variance. So what we assume at the beginning of the problem is not that we know the distribution, but rather that we know the distribution is a member of this family.

Outside of a mathematical statistics class, people do not speak as carefully. I would say that the paper you are reading is speaking loosely, and what is really meant is that you assume that the true model is in a particular family of models. And furthermore, that this family is parametrized: you can get from a list of numbers (the values of the parameters) to a model in the family, and back.

I think it's fine to speak that loosely in an economics paper for a professional audience, in order to meet wordcount, but it certainly is confusing for students, and I think classroom settings should be more precise, the way mine was.